# Converting MA(1) to AR(p)

Tags: arima, autoregressive, moving-average

While it is $MA(1)$ process there is no dependence between $u(t)$ and $u(t-1)$ i.e $$u(t)=v(t)+Q(1)v(t-1)$$ but when i converted it to AR process i get $u$’s that is dependent on the other $u$’s i.e. $$u(t)=-au(t-1)-a^2u(t-2)-a^3u(t-3)-\ldots$$ Is not in inconsistent? How those independent $u$’s become dependent after transformation?

Comment: Hi, there is no independence between $u(t)$ and $u(t-1)$, if something is unclear, please comment so that I might try to explain in more detail.

Comment: Having inverted as you can see u(t) come up as a function of past u’s. This is the question. They are not independent

Comment: Hi, they weren't independent at first place, even if you didn't write it in infinite AR form, because they both depend on $v(t-1)$. It's just they just look like as if they're independent because you don't see $u(t-1)$ in the equation.

Answer (score 1):

The second one you wrote is technically not classic $\text{AR}(p)$, where $p$ is finite. It is an *infinite autoregressive model*. Same way, a finite degree $\text{AR}$ process can be written in infinite degree $\text{MA}$ form. It's called the **Duality of MA and AR processes**. [This](https://mcs.utm.utoronto.ca/~nosedal/sta457/duality-of-ma-and-ar.pdf) is a good lecture on the topic.

By the way, $u(t)$ and $u(t-1)$ are not independent even in the first equation, because both depend on the term $v(t-1)$, e.g. if $v(t-1)$ is let's say an anomaly, both $u(t)$ and $u(t-1)$ would be affected directly.

I also want to note that similar phenomenon is present in IIR and FIR filters in signal processing, i.e. IIR filters have infinite length impulse responses and using their coefficients one can write output signal just in terms of the input signal, while the original IIR filter had an auto-regressive equation.